# How do I get a tf from specific sensor?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing a visual servoing aplication. I want a robotic arm to reach a desired position given by camera data.
I have 2 cameras in my setup to detect a single apriltag tag. The first camera is fixed far way from the tag and the other one is coupled in the arm.

The fixed camera has a wide range of vision and the arm camera has more precise position data. I want to get the transform between the tag using the data from the arm camera and, if it's not available, then get the data from the fixed camera.

I know the tf msgs have an frame_id in the header. Is it possible to use this id to get the transform?

Now I'm using "lookupTransform('world', tagString, rospy.Time(0))" to get the position but I'm not sure from which camera the data comes from.

Using Ros Melodic and Ubuntu 18.04

```
---
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 207
        nsecs: 170049000
      frame_id: "sim_camera_arm/armcameraframe_color_optical_frame"
    child_frame_id: "tag_2"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: -0.459798174616
        y: -0.109403070212
        z: 1.45586707359
      rotation: 
        x: 0.884761772023
        y: -0.197385909851
        z: 0.344390176089
        w: 0.244194217728
---
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 207
        nsecs: 210051000
      frame_id: "sim_camera/cameraframe_color_optical_frame"
    child_frame_id: "tag_2"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: -0.699637507022
        y: -0.524468569595
        z: 3.26440053099
      rotation: 
        x: 0.998620267484
        y: 0.00357684425666
        z: -0.0517392437204
        w: 0.0082351814975
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402647/how-do-i-get-a-tf-from-specific-sensor?/) by [mth_sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/103087/mth_sousa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By having two frames that are different, but both named "tag_2", you are violating the TF assumption that the tree is a simple branching structure. You need to somehow create unique names for the tag objects identified by each camera e.g. "tag_2a" and "tag_2b".

That solution also answers the question you asked: do a lookup for the (now unique) child_frame_id.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mth_sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/103087/mth_sousa/) on 2022-06-22**:
Thanks for your answer! Indeed, It's possible to publish different names for the tags frames. I just needed to edit the tags.yaml file in apriltag_ros.